# Figure subfigure layout with different numbers

Tags: subfloats, minipage, labels

I need a layout similar to the following image. However I want only the 3 images on the right side to be subfigures (2a, 2b, 3c), But the big red image on the left should be numbered as Figure 1.

[image: Layout]

Currently I am using `minipage` and the 3 blue images are not caaptioned as subfigures.

```
\begin{figure}
%   \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{merge-scenario}
        \caption{Merge Scenario}
        \label{fig:merge-scenario}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{case_a}
        \caption{State A} 
        \label{fig:case-a}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{case_b}
        \caption{State B} 
        \label{fig:case-b}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{case_c}
        \caption{State C} 
        \label{fig:case-c}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I use to do something similar with the [subcaption package](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption?lang=en), but it's been a long time. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

With use of the `subfigure` environment from the `subcation` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\thefigure\alph{subfigure}} % redefine subcaption number format
\renewcommand\p@subfigure{}
\makeatother
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % in real document remove option "demo"

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, keepaspectratio} %  common option for "includegraphics" comand
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\thefigure\alph{subfigure}}
\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[height=6cm]{merge-scenario}
    \caption{Merge Scenario}
    \label{fig:merge-scenario}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[height=1.6cm]{case_a}
\caption{State A}
    \label{fig:case-a}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[height=1.6cm]{case_b}
    \caption{State B}
    \label{fig:case-b}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[height=1.6cm]{case_c}
    \caption{State C}
    \label{fig:case-c}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**edit:**

- `Gin` keys enable to define common keys (option) for the `\includegraphics` macro. In your case this is `width` of images. Added `keppaspectratio` modify the meaning of the `width` and `height` (and `totalheight`) keys such that if both are specifed then rather than distort the figure it is scaled such that neither dimension exceeds the stated dimensions.
- for numbering of sub-figures I overlooked your demand. It can be solved as suggested @Kormylo in his comment and showed in other answer.

Comment: Thanks but I want subcaption 2a, 2b, 2c instead of (a), (b), (c) and possubly another caption for Fig 2 like usual subfigures. And what is the purpose of `\setkeys` ?

Comment: This can be fixed with \captionsetup[subfigure], but will need a \restepcounter{figure} as well.

Comment: @NeelBasu, sorry, i overlooked this. It can be solved as mentioned Jon Kormylo in above comment. I will correct my answer asap.

Comment: Can you include the subfigure number in your answer ?

Comment: @NeelBasu, sub figures are numbered as you require in question. Sorry, i don't understand you what more I should include in answer. Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Like this? (You'll have to sort out the image sizes yourself.)

```
\documentclass{article}

% for example images
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{\thefigure.\arabic{subfigure}}
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{}
\makeatother

\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}%
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{A figure.}
        \label{fig:merge-scenario}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}%
        \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}%
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{State A} 
            \label{fig:case-a}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}%
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{State B} 
            \label{fig:case-b}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}%
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
            \caption{State C} 
            \label{fig:case-c}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Another figure.}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]