# 4 (sub) Subfigures + 1 Subfigure side by side

Tags: floats, positioning, subfloats

Here is what I have tried. For reproducibility I have used `[demo]`. I want the plots on the right to be neatly placed and of the same height as the one on the left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for the example

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=5cm]{/home/ayan/Programs/David_Parkinson/Reduced_Reshaped/Elbow.pdf}
%\caption{A tall figure}
\end{subfigure}\qquad
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{/home/ayan/Programs/David_Parkinson/Reduced_Reshaped/ML_Data/BIN_1/KMeans_Cluster_1_hist.pdf}
        %\caption{}\label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{/home/ayan/Programs/David_Parkinson/Reduced_Reshaped/ML_Data/BIN_1/KMeans_Cluster_1_hist.pdf}
        %\caption{}\label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{/home/ayan/Programs/David_Parkinson/Reduced_Reshaped/ML_Data/BIN_1/KMeans_Cluster_1_hist.pdf}
        %\caption{}\label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{/home/ayan/Programs/David_Parkinson/Reduced_Reshaped/ML_Data/BIN_1/KMeans_Cluster_1_hist.pdf}
        %\caption{}\label{}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{subfigure}\qquad

\caption{The full caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: The demo plot]

[image: The real plot looks like this, with the 2X2 grids plots smaller and poorly positioned]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494129/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking from @Zarko's comment above, I modified it to suit my question :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}   
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
            \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=5cm]{/home/ayan/Programs/David_Parkinson/Reduced_Reshaped/Elbow.pdf}
                %\caption{A tall figure}
            \end{subfigure}
            &
            \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
                \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=2.5cm]{/home/ayan/Programs/David_Parkinson/Reduced_Reshaped/ML_Data/BIN_1/KMeans_Cluster_1_hist.pdf}
                    %\caption{}\label{}
                \end{subfigure}\hfill
                \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=2.5cm]{/home/ayan/Programs/David_Parkinson/Reduced_Reshaped/ML_Data/BIN_1/KMeans_Cluster_1_hist.pdf}
                    %\caption{}\label{}
                \end{subfigure}

                \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=2.5cm]{/home/ayan/Programs/David_Parkinson/Reduced_Reshaped/ML_Data/BIN_1/KMeans_Cluster_1_hist.pdf}
                    %\caption{}\label{}
                \end{subfigure}\hfill
                \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=2.5cm]{/home/ayan/Programs/David_Parkinson/Reduced_Reshaped/ML_Data/BIN_1/KMeans_Cluster_1_hist.pdf}
                    %\caption{}\label{}
                \end{subfigure}
            \end{subfigure}
        \end{tabularx}

        \caption{The full caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your images will be stretched due to usage of width and height in the same time ... Even if black images are still ok stretched this will make them at least ugly in your real document ...

Answer (score 1):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}   
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=5cm]{/home/ayan/Programs/David_Parkinson/Reduced_Reshaped/Elbow.pdf}
\caption{A tall figure}
\end{subfigure}
    &
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{/home/ayan/Programs/David_Parkinson/Reduced_Reshaped/ML_Data/BIN_1/KMeans_Cluster_1_hist.pdf}
        \caption{}\label{}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{/home/ayan/Programs/David_Parkinson/Reduced_Reshaped/ML_Data/BIN_1/KMeans_Cluster_1_hist.pdf}
        \caption{}\label{}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{/home/ayan/Programs/David_Parkinson/Reduced_Reshaped/ML_Data/BIN_1/KMeans_Cluster_1_hist.pdf}
        \caption{}\label{}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{/home/ayan/Programs/David_Parkinson/Reduced_Reshaped/ML_Data/BIN_1/KMeans_Cluster_1_hist.pdf}
        \caption{}\label{}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\end{tabularx}

\caption{The full caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

or you like to have height of the first subimage equal to height of two subimages in right column as is done in my comment given link?

Comment: HI, yes like the one in the other link, same height of the left subimage to the total height of the 2X2 subimages on the right.

Comment: but there it is 3 images