# Varied alignment of 4 images

Tags: graphics, floats, vertical-alignment, alignment

I would like to insert four images in my article as follows:
[image: (a) main image , (b),(c) and (d) on its right , vertically aligned.]

I'd like to place one main image on the left and have three smaller images on its right with a vertical alignment.
I would then given a complete description of my figures using caption.

How do I go about getting this specific alignment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Figure subfigure layout with different numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494129/figure-subfigure-layout-with-different-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach involving stacking and scaling.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,scalerel,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\setstackgap{S}{0pt}% inter-image gap
\setstackgap{L}{52pt}% baselineskip for (b) (c) (d) 
\scalerel{\includegraphics[height=10pt]{example-image}}% 10pt placeholder
{\hspace{30pt}%
  \Shortstack{%
    \includegraphics[width=70pt]{example-image-a}\\
    \includegraphics[width=70pt]{example-image-b}\\
    \includegraphics[width=70pt]{example-image-c}% 70pt actual width
}%
}
\raisebox{23pt}{\Longstack{(b)\\(c)\\(d)}}\\
(a)\hspace{118pt}
\caption{My figure of a) fruit, b) bananas, c) kiwis, and d) pomegranates}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is task for classical TeX manipulation with boxes. Only what you need to know, is behavior of `\hbox`, `\vbox`, `\vcenter` and `\vtop` TeX primitives:

```
\hbox to\hsize{%
   \vtop{\vbox{\hbox{<picture a in .7\hsize width>}}%
         \medskip\hbox to.7\hsize{\hss(a)\hss}}\hss
   \vbox to <height of big picture a>{
      \hbox{$\vcenter{\hbox{<picture b>}}$\quad(b)}\vss
      \hbox{$\vcenter{\hbox{<picture c>}}$\quad(c)}\vss
      \hbox{$\vcenter{\hbox{<picture d>}}$\quad(d)}
      \kern0pt
   }%
}
```