# How can I divide my figure like this?

Tags: subfloats

I have three pictures want to put into this way....it is quite normal
But how?

[image: How can I divide my pictures into this?]

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[tb]
        \begin{center}
            \mbox{ \begin{minipage}{0.62\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=0.62\textwidth, angle=0]{example-image-a}
                \end{minipage}
                \begin{minipage}{0.38\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, angle=0]{example-image-a} \\ 
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, angle=0]{example-image-a}
            \end{minipage} } 
            \caption{A cello made by Louise BOISSON in 2021 according to a model of P. G. Rogeri.} 
        \end{center} \label{BOISSON} 
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us the short TeX code you have tried? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing (documentclass etc.). Do you know `\includegraphics`?

Comment: You didn't quite leave enough room for the extra space.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/585361/varied-alignment-of-4-images

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, this will automatically scale any three images to fit the page within the given arrangement.  I used `\columnsep` and `\floatsep` gaps between the images.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, adjustbox}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tb]
  \sbox0{\includegraphics{example-image-10x16}}%
  \sbox1{\includegraphics{example-image-10x16}}%
  \sbox2{\includegraphics[width=\wd1]{example-image-10x16}}%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\det}{\ht1+\ht2+(\wd1/\wd0)*\ht0}% determinant/\wd0
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\scaleA}{(((\textwidth-\columnsep)/\wd0)*(\ht1+\ht2) + (\floatsep/\wd0)*\wd1)/\det}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\scaleB}{(((\textwidth-\columnsep)/\wd0)*\ht0 - \floatsep)/\det}%
  \sbox0{\scalebox{\scaleA}{\usebox0}}%
  \sbox1{\scalebox{\scaleB}{\usebox1}}%
  \sbox2{\scalebox{\scaleB}{\usebox2}}%
  \usebox0\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b][\ht0][s]{\wd1}
    \usebox1\par\vfill
    \usebox2
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

[image: explanation]

Comment: oh...my god...what are you doing? Why is it so complicate?

Comment: The revised solution is algorithmically simpler but mathematically more complex.  By putting the unscaled images into saveboxes I get the dimensions.  First I rescale the last image to be the same width as the second image. (if needed). Then I solve a pair of simultaneous equations to find two scale factors to achieve the desired spacing.

Answer (score 3):

A suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[tb]
            \begin{minipage}{0.55\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=7.75cm, angle=0]{example-image-a}
                \end{minipage}
                \hspace{0.2cm}
                \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, angle=0]{example-image-a} \\ \par
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, angle=0]{example-image-a}
            \end{minipage}
            \caption{A cello made by Louise BOISSON in 2021 according to a model of P. G. Rogeri.} 
              \label{BOISSON} 
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The \mbox is redundant, and the first minipage is only used to align the centers.

Comment: Either the minipage or the includegraphic contains a border. Is there anyway to remove it?

Comment: The border is part of the image, not added by software.