# how to Subfigure with custom position?

Tags: subfloats

I am trying to place three images in one figure using the subfigure enviorment.
I would like the two horizontal figures to be next to the larger vertical figure, so that the top edge of the upper horizontal image and the bottom edge of the lower horizontal image align with the top and bottom edge of the vertical image.

The issue is that the top horizontal image always likes to be above the vertical image.

I have tried with different position keys, but did not have success. Do you have an idea, please let me know!

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b][][b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{10Aftermath/appendix/02RT/DSC07380.JPG}
    \caption{Firts subfigure.}
    \label{fig:first}
\end{subfigure}
\vfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{10Aftermath/appendix/02RT/DSC07362.JPG}
    \caption{Third subfigure.}
    \label{fig:third}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{10Aftermath/appendix/02RT/DSC07375.JPG}
    \caption{Second subfigure.}
    \label{fig:second}
\end{subfigure}

        
\caption{Creating subfigures in \LaTeX.}
\label{fig:figures}
\end{figure}
```

[image: images not aligned correctly]

Comment: You need to put the two images on the left into a single minipage.  You can measure the height of the image on the right and use that for the optional height argument.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494129/.

Comment: Thank you for the quick pointers! That was helpful!