# How can I arrange my figures like a self-defined matrix in LaTex?

Tags: floats, subfloats, plot

I want to attach my figure like the below figure, The matrix with the independent figure or grouped subfigure. How I can make it?

[image: Matrix that i desired]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I think you forgot to add your figure. Please add also a minimal example of what you tried.

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Where is image? Seems that you forgot to add it :-)

Comment: What about captions? Is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494129/  close to what you after?

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tblr}{colsep=2pt,
             colspec={X[2.05, c,m] X[1, c,m]}
             }
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    \includegraphics[valign=m]{example-image-a}
    &   \includegraphics[valign=m]{example-image-b} \\
    &   \includegraphics[valign=m]{example-image-c} 
\end{tblr}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, i copied the code into Overleaf and don't work... plot with 3 rows...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, how you copy proposed solution into it.  I tested proposed solution in the Overleaf in new file map and it works there fine (no warnings, no errors).  T

Comment: Dear Zarko, thanks ... I find my problem: my Textlive version into Overleaf, this was configured in version 2021. I changed to 2022 and work.