# Two separate figures side by side, but the right figure has two images stacked

Tags: graphics, subfloats, minipage

I want to include 3 images. First image is a left figure and the other two are stacked in a separate figure on the right. How do I do that?

Desired output:
[image]

What I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{image1} % first figure itself
        \caption{first figure}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{image2} % second figure itself
        \caption{second figure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This produces the below output:

[image]

Comment: See, if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494129/ figure-subfigure-layout-with-different-numbers/494135#494135 can help you.

Comment: Thank you this worked. Can you post your comment as an answer so I can check it as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adopted [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494129/figure-subfigure-layout-with-different-numbers/494135#494135) to your case:

[image]

(red lines indicate  part of page layout)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex]{subcaption}

\newlength{\colwidth}
\usepackage[demo,
            export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newsavebox{\picbox}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, keepaspectratio}
\setlength\colwidth{0.33\linewidth}

\savebox{\picbox}{\parbox{\colwidth}{\addtocounter{figure}{1}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[height=22mm]{case_a}
\caption{}
    \label{fig:case-a}
    \end{subfigure}

    \smallskip
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[height=22mm]{case_b}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:case-b}
    \end{subfigure}}
    }% end of save box

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} X  @{\ } p{\colwidth}@{}}
    \includegraphics[height=\dimexpr\ht\picbox+\dp\picbox,
                     valign=c]{merge-scenario}
    \addtocounter{figure}{-1}
    \caption{Merge Scenario}
    \label{fig:merge-scenario}
&
    \usebox\picbox
    \caption{States}
    \label{fig:scenario}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}

See figure \ref{fig:scenario}, particularly \ref{fig:case-b} \dots
\end{document}
```